# Changing the video string in the video player in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to change the video stream in the video player in Matlab.
I added a button to the GUI that calls the callback anoo_callback
In the 2015a I use this script and everything is working fine.

```
function anno_callback(player)
    data = getappdata(0,'data');  %data holds 2 diffrent sets of the video with minor changes..
    anno_handle = findobj(gcf,'Tag','anno');
    if strfind(anno_handle.String, 'on')
        % turn on the annotation
        anno_handle.String = 'anno-off';
        DH = player.data.DataHandler;
        DH.UserData = data.vid_anno;
        setappdata(player.data, 'DataHandler', DH);
    else
        % turn off the annotation
        anno_handle.String = 'anno-on';
        DH = player.DataSource.DataHandler;
        DH.UserData = data.vid_noanno;
        setappdata(player.DataSource, 'DataHandler', DH);
    end
end
```

in 2016a (I changed player.data to player.DataSource) but I get this following error:

```
Error using setappdata
Input was not a valid graphics object

Error in anno_callback (line 17)
setappdata(player.DataSource, 'DataHandler', DH);
```

Does anyone have a solution for this problem? or maybe a work around?
and where can I found the changes between the Matlab's versions?